# Attribute Table numbering

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4

is there a way to reset the numbering in an attribute table in ARC 10.4? as in if features are deleted can the numbers be reordered in the new sequence left after deleting selections?

Comment: geodatabase? or shapefile?

Comment: Exporting to a another feature class will renumber the Objectid column.

Comment: can't you just add a new column with FID?

Comment: It is a shapefile and thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Please expand on your answer. As it stands, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: The OID of a shapefile is the record number (zero-based); it doesn't exist as a field in the dBase file, and will be altered by deletion upon save.  That said, the OID shouldn't be used for any purpose other than as row-number in the current manifestation of the file.

Comment: The Sort tool can sort feature classes or tables into a new fc/table based on case fields.  It handles both attribute and spatial sorts.   This may be useful if you not only want to eliminate deleted sequences, but wanted your sequential numbers ordered based on something other than the sequence in which features/records were created in the fc/table (which is what the ObjectID order represents).  Exporting and the Sequence calculation provided by CCantey cannot sort records and can only order the sequential numbers based on the original ObjectID order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you aren't trying to re-order the object id, you could just run this python script inside the field calculator:

```
#Pre-Logic Script Code:
rec=0
def autoIncrment()
  global rec
  pStart = 1
  pInterval = 1
  if (rec == 0):
    rec = pStart
  else:
    rec += pInterval
  return rec

#your field =
autoIncrement()
```

This will populate the field with new sequential numbering.